# Предложения по внесению или о внесении?

Tags: стилистика, предлоги

Как правильно: "предложения по внесению изменений и дополнений в законодательство" или "предложения о внесении изменений и дополнений в законодательство"?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что правилен следующий вариант: предложения **о внесении** изменений и дополнений в законодательство.

Применимы оба предлога, но вариант **с предлогом О** больше подходит для **новой темы,** в то время как вариант **с предлогом ПО** дополняет уже открытую ранее тему.

**Частотность** выше у варианта с предлогом О.

Примеры:

Тем временем власти Греции представили кредиторам новое **предложение по** решению долговой проблемы. [ «Эксперт», 2015]

Кроме этого, Центральный банк ОАЭ внес **предложение о** сокращении в два раза периода, который требуется для официального признания кредита невозвратным. [ (2010.01.12) // ]

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что в обоих предложениях упор делается именно на действие - внесение. Стало быть предложения надо высказывать по действию, методу, способу. Если заменить "по внесению" на "по внесённым" или "по вносимым"; а "о внесении" на "о внесённых" или "о вносимых", то предложения надо высказывать именно по изменениям или об изменениях, которые были сделаны или будут сделаны. Это другой вопрос. 
Если же всё-таки нужны предложения по внесению, то не сказано: они готовятся или уже сделаны?